# Helper class to wrap the Session for MVC.NET Web development?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889516/session-null-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-constructors) post the author recommends implementing a Wrapper for the session to ease testing and decoupling the controller code.  I will like to obtain ideas on how to implement a good wrapper for this purpose.

I see that in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/AspNetSessionHelper.aspx) there is one sample but it looks way more than what I need.

EDIT 1:

Ok. Thanks to Joshua I have implement and simple session helper class. I am posting the class here to get your opinion and see if you will add something.

```
public interface ISessionHelper
{
    T Get<T>(string key);
}

public class HttpContextSessionHelper : ISessionHelper
{
    private readonly HttpContext _context;

    public HttpContextSessionHelper(HttpContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        object value = _context.Session[key];

        return value == null ? default(T) : (T)value;
    }
}
```

In the controller I have something like this:

```
    private readonly ISessionHelper _sessionHelper;

    public HomeController(ISessionHelper session)
    {
        _sessionHelper = session;
    }

    public HomeController()
    {
        _sessionHelper = new HttpContextSessionHelper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
    }
```

Comment: How do you "set" a value into session with this wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889516/session-null-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-constructors/1020465#1020465) to that question had a comment with this [website](http://iridescence.no/post/Using-Unit-Tests-to-Uncover-Design-Flaws.aspx) that has a good simple wrapper example. The comment was made by [murki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5953/murki).