# Session across controller becomes null in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My session becomes null when I redirect to another controller's Action, what should I do?

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer on this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889516/session-null-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-constructors

Comment: Clayton, the link that you provided are talking about override the "OnActionExecuting" method and access the session there, but I don't know how to do  that, as I am new to MVC, could you help me with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I was clearing and destroying all sessions prior to setting the new session on login like this

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Session.Abandon();
Session.Clear();
```

When I removed these lines, everything started working like @Clayton  said, so I removed these lines and replaced it with `Session.Remove('sessionvariablename')`, I am still not sure what issue were the above lines causing, but my code started working.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the comment you posted me, here is what I was thinking. In the Controller where you need the session use something similar to this:

```
//Controller A
public class TheController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index(){
     Session["yourSession"] = "Hello World";
     return View();
   }
}


//Controller B
public class MyController : Controller
{
    string textString;

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext ctx)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(ctx);
        textString = ctx.HttpContext.Session["yourSession"].ToString();
    }

    public ActionResult Index(){
       string currentText = textString;
       return View();
    }
}
```

I tested the suggestion from (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889516/session-null-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-constructors), and the contents of the session were available.

Comment: And how do I set the session it?

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by "set the session", please? The Contents of the session are dynamic, so you can fill it at will. Just write - Session["myNewSessionVariable"] = "Hello World";

Comment: I have a Controller A , in that I have a Post Method for Login, where I am trying to set the Session variable like this:  `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"]=objUser`, Now after Login, I have to redirect him to another controller's Action method, There I need tocheck, `If(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"]!=null)`, but here I am always getting it as NULL

Comment: Yes that's correct. From the OnActionExecuting method, which should be found in Controller B, just use the following -  User user = (User)ctx.HttpContext.Session["User"]; The User object can be placed as a class variable so that you can access it from any Action method you like.

Comment: Just to clarify, when I say "User Object", I'm actually referring to what you're placing in the Session.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did, I have implemented a base controller and overridden OnActionExecuting method there in that I wrote `UserInfo = (UserAccountModel)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["LoggedInDentist"];` but I receive NULL value :(

Comment: And you're sure that the UserInfo object you're placing in Controller A is not null to begin with? It's odd cause I just tried this and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yes its not null, in that same controller, If I call any other Action method of same controller, I get it's value, but the moment it goes across controller, it becomes null, I even tried `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" >
      <remove name="Session" />
      <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/> 
    </modules>` in the main config file and not the config file of Views but it is still not working

Comment: Try removing those items you placed in the config file. I will edit my answer to what I did in mine and it should be enough.

Comment: I tried your above sample in separate application and it is truely working, and I have a feeling that, it has got to do something with routing, I have 4 custom routers above the default router in my global.asax, could that be a problem?

Comment: I doubt that that's the problem since the Session should be accessible throughout the whole project, regardless of routing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a unique base controller with a session property, then all controllers within your project will inherit from that BaseController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MonitoringCSP.Controllers
{
//[AllowAnonymous]
//[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private HttpSessionStateBase _session;
    protected HttpSessionStateBase CrossControllerSession
    {
        get
        {
            if (_session == null) _session = Session;
            return _session;
        }
        set {
                _session = Session;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage sample

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System.Web.Routing;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using MonitoringCSP.Models;

    namespace MonitoringCSP.Controllers
    {
[AllowAnonymous]
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
                /*session*/
                CrossControllerSession["UserName"] = User.Identity.Name;
                /*end session*/
        return RedirectToAction("someAction");
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your controller does not have this attribute set on it:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
```