# Can't retrieve the value in HttpContext.Current.Session state

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC 4 web app. I saved a value in the session defined in "Session_Start" in the MvcApplication class in the Global.asax.cs file.

I would like to retrieve the value from the Controller. But it threw out an error.

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("_SessionCompany", temp);
            Debug.WriteLine("session started");
        }
```

In the constructor of the Controller:

```
public LocationController()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session == null)
                Debug.WriteLine("session is null");
            //this.HttpContext.Session["_SessionCompany"] = (int)this.Session["_SessionCompany"] + 1;
            //Debug.WriteLine("LocationController instantiated - " + (int)this.Session["_SessionCompany"]);
        }
```

The error is on HttpContext:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It seems the HttpContext is null object.

Where am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Session null in ASP.Net MVC Controller Constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889516/session-null-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-constructors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HttpContext` object you're trying to access is located within the ASP.NET MVC's base `Controller` class which is not set at the point the controller is instantiated, and is instead inject at a later date.

If you wish to access the HTTPContext object within your constructor then you'll need to inject it via an IoC container using [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (the recommended solution), or you could access the context directly like so:

```
using SystemWebHttpContext = System.Web.HttpContext;

...

public LocationController()
{
    var session = SystemWebHttpContext.Current.Session;
}
```