# Getting user information on class level in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity

In `ASP.NET Identity 2 or 3`, is it possible to get user info on a class level? Scenario is as follows: There are only two Roles in the app, namely `AdminRole` and `RegRole`. A user in an AdminRole can act as a user in UserRole by selecting a user name from a dropdown that is available only to the AdminRole user. What I need to do is that if an Admin selects a user from the dropdown from home page, I need to assign the name of the selected user to a class (that is a Controller) level variable so that user name can be used on all action methods of that Controller (a class). I tried the following but it throws NullException at `if (User.Identity.Name == "Admin")` line of the code below:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**Home Controller** [Where admin selects a user name from a dropdown]

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ChooseUser(string selectedUser)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeySelUser, selectedUser);

        return View();
    }
}
```

**Other Controller** [Where I want to use selected user name from above in all action methods of following Controller]

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
   private MyProjContext _context;
   private string _userName;

  public TestController (MyProjContext context)
  {
    _context = context;

    if (User.Identity.Name == "Admin")
        _userName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedUser"); //This session variable was assigned the user name value when the admin had selected the user name from the dropdown on the home page
   }
}

//use the class level variable _userName in all action methods like the one below
public IActionResult TestAction()
{
    _context.Orders.Where(ord => ord.Seller == _userName);

    return View();
}

....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Identity 3`, you must get an instance of `UserManager` in order to get the current logged in user.

You can get an instance of `UserManager` using `iOC` and then use the `GetUserAsync` method of `UserManager` to get the current user object model.

```
protected readonly UserManager<AppUser> UserManager;
private Task<AppUser> GetCurrentUserAsync() => UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);

public TestController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager)
{
     UserManager = userManager;
}
```

Your condition can be changed as this:

```
var curUser = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
if (curUser.Name == "Admin")
        _userName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedUser"); //This session variable was assigned the user name value when the admin had selected the user name from the dropdown on the home page
```

Since you are trying to access it from the constructor, you can add `Result` in front to make it synchronous. As you reported on comments, the HttpContext of the controller is null when the class is being constructed. Nevertheless, you can access it from IHttpContextAccessor.

```
public TestController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    UserManager = userManager;
    var curUser = UserManager.GetUserAsync(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User).Result;
    if (curUser.Name == "Admin")
        _userName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("selectedUser"); 
}
```

If you use `Identity`, I believe that `IHttpContextAccessor` is injected into the pipeline. If it returns null, you must add it as a singleton in your `Startup` class.

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

Comment: I assume by `Task<AppUser>` you meant `Task<ApplicationUser>`. Anyhow, on line `GetCurrentUserAsync.Name == "Admin"` I'm getting error: **Task<ApplicationUser>` does not contain a definition for Name**.

Comment: You're right. I just updated the answer. I use a custom user, that is why I named the class AppUser. The default is ApplicationUser.

Comment: Damn. Change it from property to method and see if it works. Just add () to the GetCurrentUserAsync definition and call. I'm on mobile at the moment and can't test it...

Comment: Ok, just noted that you are trying to access it from the constructor. I updated the answer to fit your needs.

Comment: Now I'm getting the `NULLException` at the line `var curUser = UserManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User).Result;`. It seems accessing user is not possible inside a `Controller's Constructor` as explained by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1212451/1232087).

Comment: You are right once again... :) But you can access `HttpContext` from the `IHttpContextAccessor` that is initiated with the request. Check the updated answer.