# Session Value is NULL after saving it using SQL Server Session State

Tags: c#, sql-server, session-state

I recently converted my App to use Session State "SQL Sever" instead of "InProc" as I had to do some redirects to a third-party app. Everything is working ok and I can set and retrieve session values easily. The problem occurs when I try to access the Session again from a different Controller method

This is how it is structured:

**Add Company Method**

```
public String AddNewCompany()
    {
       SalesInvoiceSettingController invoiceSetting = new SalesInvoiceSettingController();
       string Uname = Session["UserName"].ToString(); // This session value is picked correctly
     
     invoiceSetting.SaveInvoiceSettings(); // This is another method which I am calling inside this method, by creating an object of 'SalesInvoiceSettingController'
```

**The SaveInvoiceSettings Method**

```
 public string SaveInvoiceSettings()
    {
        
        string Uname = Session["UserName"].ToString(); <-- This is where I get a NULL POINTER EXCEPTION i.e Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong here? it`s accessible from a method of one controller but not from a method of a different controller. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You're creating an instance of a controller inside another controller? Why? A better design would be for them to share a business layer object. I'm not sure if this is the cause, but you newing up a controller will do different things in the lifecycle than if the framework does it?

Comment: I can understand the design flaw here. What I can’t understand is why exactly is this issue occurring though? Could it be that the instance is causing the issue?

Comment: Possibly. I'm not sure how you're instantiating the controller, but it's possible the Session state is handled by the framework and injected at some point when it creates the controller, but not when you do, since you're not passing along a context where it comes from.

Comment: Ah, this looks interesting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889516/session-null-in-asp-net-mvc-controller-constructors  Perhaps you can set the httpcontext and pass session that way

Comment: Wow.... ok this indeed looks interesting... I`ll have a look

Comment: @Nikki9696... youre a life saver. This helped alot. I have posted the answer as well below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally found the reason why this was happening. Basically as per the Framework, when you create an Instance , It doesnt really initialize it completely (i.e No Sessions, Request etc) are initialized but actually are 'Injected' later on in the process Life Cycle. In Order to resolve this issue , we would need to manually Initialize it. The solution is below on how to do it:

Consider Two Controllers:

- Controller A (The controller where the Instance of 'Controller B' is created).
- Controller B

First you need to create a method for Initialization in Controller B like this:

**Controller B**

```
  Public class ControllerB : Controller
{
    public void InitializeController(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
       
    }
   }
```

Now, create the instance for Controller B in Controller A and call this method:

**Controller A**

```
Public Class ControllerA : Controller
 {
   ControllerB obj1 = new ControllerB();
   obj1.InitializeController.InitializeController(this.Request.RequestContext);
  }
```

And you are good to go. You will have full access to all sessions.
Thanks to **nikki9696** for pointing me to the right direction.